# Accessing child component value in Parent component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am having an angualr 2 application and I loading child components in parent components using *ngFor.
But I am facing a issue while I try to pass value from child to parent using @Output because it always return the value from first child component of *ngFor to the parent. Actually It should return the value from respective child component on which @Output event is emitted.

Any idea what is the issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post code instead of explaining the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. I made a silly mistake in child component. Instead of having one root element I kept multiple root HTML elements in child components. I made changes by having only one HTML root element in child component and things working as needed.

Thanks for your time.